# Store value returned by file test operator in Perl

Tags: perl

How can I store value returned by `-M $file` operator in Perl in a variable and later use in a mathematical expression? I have tried this on an existing file:

```
DB<1> $file="file.txt"

DB<2> $a=`-M $file`;

DB<3> print "$a"
```

But that does not seem to work.

Comment: You mean as in `my $result = -M $file;`?

Comment: yes exactly , Is there any way ?

Comment: What's wrong with the want in @PerlDuck's comment?

Comment: @downvoters : I would also be interested to know the reason for downvote so that I can improve myself and my questions :).

Comment: @Vicky: I haven't downvoted. But I would guess it's because you haven't explained what you have tried and what problems you are having.

Comment: These types of questions get closed as too broad all the time because it shows no effort that you attempted to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Thanks but I did not really have any idea for how to go about that , nonetheless I have edited with what I have tried , can't think of anything else.

Comment: Thanks , I will make sure I post my question with what I tried now on.

Comment: @Vicky: If every newcomer posted questions of as high quality as most of yours, I think we'd all be very happy :-)

Comment: Vicky, you seem to want to learn a lot about Perl, and many of the questions you ask here involve existing code. I wonder, are you getting this code at work? Have you been dumped on a legacy code base without a lot of knowledge about Perl? But then some of the questions are more general, like this one about debugging (though I think you used the debugger as a REPL) or the one about formats. This is not a critique, I am just curious. What's your situation? :)

Comment: @simbabque , yes I have been given existing code to work on after a short  curtain raiser training on Perl, the code given to me is written by people who left the organisation  :-)  I dont have any perl expert around me for guidance. I am reading books and perldocs but I get stuck sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take the value returned by a file test operator and store in a variable by... well... by taking the value and storing it in a variable.

```
my $mod_time = -M $some_file;
```

Then later you can treat `$mod_time` as you would treat any scalar variable (because that's what it is).

**Update:** You've just updated your question to show what you've tried:

```
$ a= `-M $file`;
```

But `-M $file` is not an external command, so you don't need the backticks.